# How to copy multiple files based on date modified using batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I want to make the files copy command based on date modified from other folder.

I have batch file like this, but this only can copy one file

```
@echo off
set folder1=D:\FTP-NSQM\2G_VOLUME\2017
set folder2=D:\FTP-NSQM\newday\2gvolume
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /o-d "%folder1%\*.csv"') do copy "%folder1%\%%~a" "%folder2%" & goto next
:next
echo Carrying on with rest of batch
pause
```

How to copy multiple files at last modified?

For example, I have files like this. I want copy file a.csv, b.csv, and c.csv from folder 1 to folder 2 
And if possible, I want to delete the previous data on folder 2 (d.csv, e.csv,and f.csv)

```
+--------------------------+  +--------------------------+
|       folder 1           |  |     folder 2 (before)    |
+----------+---------------+  +----------+---------------+
|   name   | date modified |  |   name   | date modified |
+----------+---------------+  +----------+---------------+
| a.csv    | 2017-07-26    |  | d.csv    | 2017-07-25    |
| b.csv    | 2017-07-26    |  | e.csv    | 2017-07-25    |
| c.csv    | 2017-07-26    |  | f.csv    | 2017-07-25    |
| d.csv    | 2017-07-25    |  +----------+---------------+
| e.csv    | 2017-07-25    |      I hope :) be like this
| f.csv    | 2017-07-25    |  +--------------------------+
| g.csv    | 2017-07-24    |  |     folder 2 (after)     |
| h.csv    | 2017-07-24    |  +----------+---------------+
| i.csv    | 2017-07-24    |  |   name   | date modified |
| .....    | ....-..-..    |  +----------+---------------+
+----------+---------------+  | a.csv    | 2017-07-26    |
                              | b.csv    | 2017-07-26    |
                              | c.csv    | 2017-07-26    |
                              +----------+---------------+
```

Comment: What is the criteria. I can find out the date modified. But do I have to copy files that have their date modified crossed a particular date or what?

Comment: I want to copy last date modified :)

Comment: In the line that begins with 'do' you need a colon (:next)

Comment: You posted code cannot work as there is a syntax error. Could the problem be restated as you want to copy those files that do not currently exist in the second directory? Do you also want to copy files in the first directory that *do* exist in the second if the filedate in the first is different from that in the second?

Comment: @Marichyasana : no, you do not need a colon in a `goto` *except* in the specific case of `goto :eof`. In fact, I recommend *never* to use a colon in a `goto` except for the `goto :eof`

Comment: @Magoo Thanks, I didn't know that.

Comment: @Magoo sorry, i have updated my script (this work for me, but just can copied one file)

Comment: remove to `&goto next` to complete the copy of all files **BUT** with your current code, all that will do is copy **ALL** of the files to the second directory. We need to know which files to copy to and which to delete  from the second directory - which is actually why I asked the question, believe it or not...:)

Comment: thanks @Magoo, I want copy all newer files from folder 1 to folder 2, and delete older files from folder 2 :)

Comment: So - you actually want to copy those files that are in folder1 and have the latest date into folder2 and delete those files that are in folder2 that do *not* have (the latest date from folder1) ?

Comment: Yes, i want like that
I want copy all new files from folder 1 (at date greater than folder 2 last date  )

Comment: So do you want to copy today's files from `folder 1` to `folder 2` and to remove everything else from there? if so, you could do this: `del /S /Q "D:\path\to\folder 2\*.*" & forfiles /P "D:\path\to\folder 1" /M "*" /D +0 /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE for %%F in (@file) do copy /Y @path 0x22D:\path\to\folder 2\%%~F0x22 > nul"`; alternatively, you could do this (copy files not older than 24 hours): `del /S /Q "D:\path\to\folder 2\*.*" & robocopy "D:\path\to\folder 1" "D:\path\to\folder 2" "*.*" /MAXAGE:1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
:: remove all .csv files from destination
del "%folder2%\*.csv"
pushd "%folder1%"
:: date lastdate to the latest date/time of a file in folder1
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /o-d "*.csv"') do set "lastdate=%%~ta"& goto next
:next
:: grab first 8 characters (may need to be 10, depending on your date/time format)
:: - get the date part only
set "lastdate=%lastdate:~0,8%"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /o-d "*.csv"') do echo "%%~ta" | find "%lastdate%" >nul & if errorlevel 1 (
 goto done
 ) else (copy "%%~a" "%folder2%")
)
:done
popd
```

So - first clear *folder2*, then switch the current directory to *folder1*

set `lastdate` to the date/time string from the first .csv found in reverse-date order and remove the time portion.

Run through the directory again and see whether to date found in `lastdate` matches the file's date. If it does, `errorlevel` will be set to 0, otherwise to non-zero.

The `if errorlevel` test interprets the current value of `errorlevel`, and evaluates to `true` if the value of `errorlevel` is the nominated value or greater, otherwise to false, so we need to copy the file if `errorlevel` is `0` (the date matches `lastdate`) and since the files are being listed in date-order, finding the first non-match will mean that the remaining files will also be a non-match on date, so we can exit from the`for` loop to `done` and `pop` back to the original directory.

Comment: Thank you very much, its work :), but Your forget double quote on `('dir /b /a-d /o-d *.csv"')` be `('dir /b /a-d /o-d "*.csv"')`

Comment: Hai @Magoo, how to set lastdate as last date from folder 2?

Comment: I have tried `('dir /b /a-d /o-d "%folder2%\*.csv"') do set "lastdate=%%~ta"`, this not work (no one copied)

Comment: I do not understand why you need the last date from `folder2` as it doesn't relate to your question. However, you would need to `pushd "%folder2%"` then execute the `dir` command, setting `lastdate2`, then exit to `:next2` and grab the date from `lastdate2` in the same way as `lastdate` is set from `folder1`. Then `ppd` which will return you to your original directory. Sadly, using `%%~t?` will assign the timestamp from the fileNAME in `%%?` BUT from the **current** directory (if it exists)

Answer (score 0):

This should work ->

```
@echo off
set folder1=D:\FTP-NSQM\2G_VOLUME\2017
set folder2=D:\FTP-NSQM\newday\2gvolume
set dateFlag=""
cd %folder2%
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /od') do @set dateFlag=%%~ta
set dateFlag=%dateFlag:~0,10%
cd ..
del %folder2%
mkdir %folder2%
echo latest date= %dateFlag%
cd %folder1%
FORFILES /D +%dateFlag% /C "cmd /c copy @file %folder2/"
```

Comment: Thanks @Trishant Pahwa, but this not work for me :)
i have erro on `/Q is not recorgnized as an internal or external command, operable program or btch file.` and `Invalid switch - "*".`

Comment: Try now maybe??